# Dialog in Android Studio following course

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, dialog

I'm currently following a Kotlin course. In here, an xml file is used for a `Dialog`. This looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<ImageButton
    android:id = "@+id/ib_small_brush"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/small"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ib_medium_brush"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id = "@+id/ib_medium_brush"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/medium"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ib_small_brush"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ib_large_brush"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id = "@+id/ib_large_brush"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/medium"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ib_medium_brush"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I had the issue that some of the attributes like `android:id` and `android:src` didn't automatically pop up when I started typing them out, unlike other attributes.

This is my `MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var drawingView: DrawingView? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    drawingView = findViewById(R.id.drawing_view)
    drawingView?.setSizeForBrush(20.toFloat())
}

private fun showBrushSizeChooserDialog(){
    val brushDialog = Dialog(this)
    brushDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_brush_size)
    brushDialog.setTitle("Brush size: ")
    val smallButton = brushDialog.ib
}}
```

In the course, the `ImageViews` are accessed through `brushDialog.ib_small_brush` for example and then used to set onClickListeners on them etc. However, this is not possible for me. Is this way of doing it outdated (using fragments instead) or is there something fundamentally wrong with my code or Android Studio?

Cheers.

Comment: "However, this is not possible for me." - What is not possible for you? Why not? What is your expectation? What is happening instead? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @dominicoder When accessing the class via the '.' operator, there is no option to select the ID's of the ImageViews. I need to access them to use other operations on them.

Comment: What is "the class"? Do you have the course example to reference? Can you comment your code snippet to show exactly where the issue is and what you're expecting to work there?

Comment: val smallButton = brushDialog.ib --> this should be brushDialog.ib_small_brush. This doesn't get recognized by the compiler

Answer (score 0):

> this should be brushDialog.ib_small_brush

You still haven't shown the course example you're using so I'm going to take a guess.

`brushDialog.ib_small_brush` looks like you're trying to use ViewBinding. But `brushDialog` is a `Dialog`, so of course that's not going to work.

You need to create a ViewBinging for that layout file. Something like this:

```
private fun showBrushSizeChooserDialog() {
    val brushDialog = Dialog(this)
    
    // Create binding from the dialog layout file
    val binding = NameOfLayoutFileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    
    // Set the inflated view as the content
    brushDialog.setContentView(binding.root)
    
    brushDialog.setTitle("Brush size: ")
    
    // Access views via the binding
    val smallButton = brushDialog.ib_small_brush
}
```

Review [the documentation on ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) for more information.